# Utilizar uma web api como dll é possível?

Tags: .net, dll

Após feito o publish de um projeto Web API adicionei nas referencias a dll dessa API em outra solution, a intenção é "consumir" essa API sem httpclient, para acessar os métodos do controller dessa API.

Isso é possível?

Tentei mas quando chamo o namespace apiService.Controller.TesteController() é exigido a interface que está na injeção do controller, e não tenho acesso a isso pela DLL, por isso vem a quentão se é possível o que estou tentando fazer, se sim onde estou errando?

Comment: Até é possível, mas é uma coisa meio estranha de se fazer. De qualquer forma, como você pretende criar uma instância de `TesteController` sem passar os parâmetros do construtor? Veja bem, se tem algo sendo "injetado" no construtor, é porque o controller usa isto, se o controller usa isto e você não passa isso para ele, como funcionaria?

Comment: Pois é, mas no projeto da API tem um container de injeção que resolve isso, depois de compilado não já deveria está tudo funcionando?

Comment: Não é assim que funciona. Sugiro que você pare para estudar um pouco sobre como funciona essa injeção de dependência.

Comment: Abandonei a ideia, vi que é muita gambiarra que estou pensando em fazer, obrigado pela ajuda.